# How to decode URL with 4-digit escaped characters with Python?

Tags: python, encoding, wikipedia

Decoding normal URL escaped characters is a fairly easy task with python.

If you want to decode something like: `Wikivoyage:%E5%88%A0%E9%99%A4%E8%A1%A8%E5%86%B3`

All you need to use is:

```
import urllib
urllib.parse.unquote('Wikivoyage:%E5%88%A0%E9%99%A4%E8%A1%A8%E5%86%B3')
```

And you get: `'Wikivoyage:删除表决'`

However, I have identified some characters which this does not work with, namely 4-digit % encoded strings:

- For example: `%25D8`
- This apparently decodes to `◘`
- But if you use the urllib function I demonstrated previously, you get: `%D8`

I understand why this happens, the unquote command reads the `%25` as a `'%'`, which is what it normally translates to. Is there any way to get Python to read this properly? Especially in a string of similar characters?

Comment: What do you mean "apparently"? Sure your data was not incorrectly encoded? I think `%E2%97%98` is the url encoding of `chr(0x25d8)` ("INVERSE BULLET") character - i.e. quoting from the utf-8 encoded bytes.

Comment: The data I am pulling from is just a list of url-encoded strings. One of the example strings I am trying to decode is represented as:

%25D8%25A5%25D8%25B2%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D8%25A9_%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D8%25B4%25D8%25B9%25D8%25B1_%25D8%25A8%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D9%2584%25D9%258A%25D8%25B2%25D8%25B1


This is the raw form of it. Other strings are normal url escapes such as: 
%D8%A5%D9%88%D8%B2

Comment: That first one is a doubly-encoded string.  unquote it twice and you will get إزالة_الشعر_بالليزر  ("laser hair removal" :)

Comment: If I may get a single or double decoded string, is there a way to safely double decode without screwing up single-decoded strings?

Comment: @JoshKraushaar Not really, it was already screwed up at the source of the encoding and needs to be addressed there instead. You can apply some guesswork or heuristics though (e.g. if there are a lot of "%25" present then double-encoded is likely)

Comment: @JoshKraushaar Could you please add those examples to the question? Apparently you were mistaken about the decoding, which is crucial for anyone writing an answer. **Edit**: To be clear, if it actually were `◘`, `%25D8` could be interpreted as malformed UTF-32.

Answer (score 1):

### The actual problem

In [a comment](/questions/68534611/#comment121120810_68534611) you posted the real examples:

> The data I am pulling from is just a list of url-encoded strings. One of the example strings I am trying to decode is represented as: `%25D8%25A5%25D8%25B2%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D8%25A9_%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D8%25B4%25D8%25B9%25D8%25B1_%25D8%25A8%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D9%2584%25D9%258A%25D8%25B2%25D8%25B1` This is the raw form of it. Other strings are normal url escapes such as: `%D8%A5%D9%88%D8%B2`

The first one is double-quoted, [as wim pointed out](/questions/68534611/#comment121120836_68534611). So they unquote as: `إزالة_الشعر_بالليزر` and `إوز` (which are Arabic for "laser hair removal" and "geese").

So you were mistaken about the unquoting and `◘` is a red herring.

---

### Solution

Ideally you would fix whatever gave you this inconsistent data, but if nothing else, you could try detecting double-quoted strings, for example, by checking if the number of `%` equals the number of `%25`.

```
def unquote_possibly_double_quoted(s: str) -> str:
    if s.count('%') == s.count('%25'):
        # Double
        s = urllib.parse.unquote(s)
    return urllib.parse.unquote(s)
```

```
>>> s = '%25D8%25A5%25D8%25B2%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D8%25A9_%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D8%25B4%25D8%25B9%25D8%25B1_%25D8%25A8%25D8%25A7%25D9%2584%25D9%2584%25D9%258A%25D8%25B2%25D8%25B1'
>>> unquote_possibly_double_quoted(s)
'إزالة_الشعر_بالليزر'
>>> unquote_possibly_double_quoted('%D8%A5%D9%88%D8%B2')
'إوز'
```

You might want to add some checks to this, like for example, `s.count('%') > 0` (or `'%' in s`).